# How to show spinner (or anything else) on page load in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5, spinner, onload

I'm trying to show an image on page load (and the general idea is to show a spinner) but it doesn't show up:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-form',
    templateUrl: './form.component.html'
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

    loading = true;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loading = true;
    }

}
```

In the html:

```
<app-form>
    <img *ngIf="loading" src="/assets/img/logo.png" />
</app-form>
```

`form.component` template sits within `<app>` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the html of `form.component.html` to:

```
<img *ngIf="loading" src="/assets/img/logo.png" />
```

No need for `<app-form></app-form>`, put that in the parent component's html

Comment: It shows up now but only together with the other content of the page, I want to show it on loading while waiting to the page to load. Is it possible? @jcroll

Answer (score 2):

I do this on a lot of my projects that I'm currently working on. The best way is.

Inside your `form.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-form',
    templateUrl: './form.component.html'
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

    loading = true;
    loaded = false;

    constructor() { }

    async ngOnInit() {
        try {
            await this.getData(); // DataCall
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Error', err);
        }
        this.loaded = true;
        this.loading = false;
    }

}
```

Then on your `form.component.html`

```
<img *ngIf="!loading" src="/assets/img/logo.png" />
<ng-container *ngIf="loaded">
    ...
    // Page Content
    ...
</ng-container>
```